# MassTransit - Publish message from a RawJson consumer

Tags: .net, serialization, microservices, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have a consumer configured with the **UseRawJsonSerializer()** method. After applying some business logic, the consumer needs to publish an event. However, I am facing a problem: the event consumer (currently only one) raises an exception related to the missing **envelope**. I believe this is because the first consumer does not have the envelope. However, since it's an internal communication between my services, I would like to send the envelope and avoid using the RawJsonSerializer everywhere. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the raw JSON deserializer without changing the format of outgoing messages.

```cs
endpoint.UseRawJsonDeserializer(isDefault: maybe);
```

> Use `true` if no ContentType on incoming message, otherwise `false`

This will leave outbound messages to be serialized as JSON with the envelope.